# JavaMail failed to create new store connection

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am using Java mail API and  getting this Error while moving mails.
Below is the code and Exception.

```
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        Store store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect(ipAdd, userid , password);
          Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
         inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
         Folder test = store.getFolder("Emails");
          //Create the destination folder if it does not exist
         if (!test.exists())
         test.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
         Message[] msgs = inbox.getMessages(from, to);
         inbox.copyMessages(msgs, test);
         inbox.setFlags(msgs, new Flags(Flags.Flag.DELETED), true);

         inbox.close(false);
         test.close(false);
```

Exception:

- javax.mail.StoreClosedException:

Comment: What does the stack trace show?  Exactly which line of the program is causing the exception?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show when this happens?